# Bookmarklet to show deleted messages in chat

Tags: script, bookmarklet

The following bookmarklet lets mods and room owners see deleted messages in chat and chat transcripts. Useful for when a lot of messages have been deleting and picking through the ruins is proving tough.

```
javascript:$('.message:has(.deleted)').each(function(){var mid=this.id.split('-')[1];$.get('http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/'+mid+'/history',function(data){$('#message-'+mid).css('color','red').html($(data).find('.message:eq(0)').html())})})
```

Comment: Related: [#1 GitHub's SOUP](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/issues/1)

Comment: This is great, thanks! Should have more rep than just 15 from this :)

Comment: 10k+ users cannot see deleted messages in chat, [only mods and room owners](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134917/155739).

Comment: Also, change `http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages` to `/messages` So that it works with (a) HTTPS, and (b) SO chat.

Comment: Might also want to append `<small>[deleted]</small>` to the new content, or instead change the _background_ colour or something, as link-only removed messages do not show up the redness and therefore are indistinguishable.

Comment: @enderland on Stack Apps, question upvotes are also worth 10, so it would be 30. And make that 40! :)